# Android GridLayout with buttons running off screen

Tags: android, xml, button, tablelayout

Trying to get the hang of GridLayout, I've run into what seems to be a very basic problem with the buttons running off the screen. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf=8" ?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="5">

    <Button android:text="A" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0" />
    <Button android:text="B" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="1" />
    <Button android:text="C" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="2" />
    <Button android:text="D" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="3" />
    <Button android:text="E" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="4" />

</GridLayout>
```

Up to 4 columns and it works fine. At 5 columss, it starts running off the screen.

I want the buttons to fill the width of the screen exactly, stretching or shrinking if necessary. Ideally, the buttons would all be the same size as well.

I have tried TableLayout, and it does the same thing as GridLayout, pushing the buttons right off the screen.

In HTML you would do this by specifying that the table width be 100%, and each table cell be 20%. But I cannot figure out how to accomplish this seemingly trivial task using Android XML.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a weight for the buttons?

Comment: You could use a  horizontal Linear Layout and assign weights to the buttons if you only need one row